# Can I OR views filter criteria

Tags: views

I'm sure this should be simple and I'm missing something because I'm tired on a Friday afternoon.

I have a Content Type (which I didn't design!) with fields "Start Date" and "Start Month". I want to show items in the View if EITHER "Start Date" OR "Start Month" are non-empty. However it seems that multiple Filter Criteria in the View are AND-ed ?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create new filter group and `OR` them. Just use `And/Or, Rearrange` from drop-down Filter criteria. Use filter groups as per your needs. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Kumar - this was very helpful. This was a Views feature I haven't seen before (I haven't built many Views.) Best regards, MB